# How to print all possible grades in a recursive or any other way?

Tags: prolog

Ok,i have implemented the predicate `show(Name,Grade).`
which works like this

```
?-show(Name,8).
Name=Jim;
Name=Ann;
false
?-show('Jim',Grade).
Grade=8;
false
```

I want to build a predicate `worstGrades(Name,Grade)` that finds the worst student in class implementing `show(Name,Grade)` somehow and by pressing `;` returns second worst student,then the third etc like this

```
?-worstGrades(Name,Grade).
Name=Bob,Grade=3;
Name=Max,Grade=5;
Name=Pete,Grade=5; 
....
```

> I think the solution  has something to do with accessing `show(Name,Grade)` recursively with Grades variable ranging from (0,10),but I can't think of a way to do it at the moment.Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
show('Jim',8).
show('Anne',8).
show('bob',6).
show('fred',7).


worst_grades(Name,Grade):-
    setof(Grade-Name,show(Name,Grade),Grades),
    member(Grade-Name,Grades).
```

Query:

```
?-worst_grades(Name,Grade).
Grade = 6,
Name = bob;
Grade = 7,
Name = fred;
Grade = 8,
Name = 'Anne';
Grade = 8,
Name = 'Jim'
```

Comment: Thanks so much friend ! The problem I described was a simplified version of a bit more complex problem that I'm working on and I used the mentality of your solution to solve my problem.Thanks again,have a good day